# How to enable a control after a row is selected in Radgrid

Tags: telerik-grid, radgrid

Im using a Radgrid. I have a Textbox that is disabled, but I would like to enable it when any row is selected in the Radgrid.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below link. I have already given the answer for same.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-enable-a-control-after-a-row-is-selected-in-radgrid.aspx#2645690

Let me know if any concern.